# Sum all unique pair differences in a vector

Tags: python

I have the following problem: given a vector `x` of length `n`, find all but sum of unique pairwise differences of the vector elements.
One should not consider the pairs where the operands are merely exchanged, just one of them (e.g. do not consider `(x_i - x_j)` if `(x_j - x_i)` was computed).

For example:

```
v = [4, 2, 1, 5]
```

Sum: (4-2) + (4-1) + (4-5) + (2-1) + (2-5) + (1-5)

It is very easy to do this with two nested for loops. I need this to be computed very efficiently in Python since each such sum is then used together with a very large and sparse matrix. I am  repeatedly processing the vectors with sizes of tens of thousands elements.

Is there a more elegant approach? In R one could use the `outer` function where instead of multiplication, use difference operator, then take upper tridiagonal part of matrix and compute sum of the resulting matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the `k`th element is added `(n - 1 - 2 * k)` times, where `n` is the length of the array. So you can just do this:

```
v = [4, 2, 1, 5]

n = len(v)
s = 0 # this is going to be the sum
for idx, x in enumerate(v):
    s += (n - 1 - 2 * idx) * x
print s
```

Comment: All answers provide the solution I was looking for, so not 100% sure which one to pick as the best. Arguably picking the one which is the most easy to read and showing understanding of the problem.

Comment: Vectorising this with numpy arrays will probably be quite a bit faster with many elements.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon Yes, I am actually working with numpy arrays and matrices. Didn't wish to mix them in the original question (perhaps I should have?).

Comment: FWIW, `s = ((n - 1 - 2*numpy.arange(N))*v).sum()` was about 100 times faster in my tests if v was already a `numpy.array`

Answer (score 3):

you can use `itertools.combinations` and `map()` function  :

```
sum(map(lambda x :x[0]-x[1] ,combinations(v,2)))
```

Demo :

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> from operator import sub
>>> list(combinations(v,2))
[(4, 2), (4, 1), (4, 5), (2, 1), (2, 5), (1, 5)]
>>> [sub(i,j) for i,j in list(combinations(v,2))]
[2, 3, -1, 1, -3, -4]
>>> sum([sub(i,j) for i,j in list(combinations(v,2))])
-2
```

Comment: The first command using the lambda function is way too slow for my 20000 long vectors. The other with sum, sub and combinations works great!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that if there's a choice between computing `x_i - x_j` and `x_j - x_i`, and `i < j`, then you choose `x_i - x_j`.  Then the answer is:

```
n = len(v)
sum([(n - 1 - 2*i)*x for i, x in enumerate(v)])
```